# loading a web.xml from groovy app in netbeans

Tags: grails, groovy, web.xml

I am applying some security constraints in web.xml  under WEB-INF folder in web application like:

```
<web-app>
    <security-constraint>
       <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name >precluded methods</web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern >/css/*</url-pattern>
         <url-pattern >/js/*</url-pattern>
         <url-pattern >/swf/*</url-pattern>
         </web-resource-collection>
       <auth-constraint/>
     </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

Now I want these to be applied (inserted into ) to the web.xml which is generated when I create the WAR using command grails WAR. Right now the command create a default web.xml which doesn't include above code, its autogenerated with some other mappings. I need to manually copy paste above code into the exploded wars web.xml to make it work. How do I have a local copy of web.xml which will have these securty coonstraints and they will get appended to the generated web.xml once I build the war. (I am using netbeans IDE which uses jetty server for grails app)

Regards
Priyank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run:

```
grails install-templates
```

it should put a copy of `web.xml` in `src/templates/war` which you can edit, and Grails will use when it runs or builds the war

Answer (score 0):

can you try this way, i guess it can solve your problem. Open war file with winrar, find your web.xml and delete it. And then put your local web.xml to there.

Comment: I am doing the same right now, manually going into the web.xml of the war and pasting the above code, I need to be able to automate this to have the constraints set once in the code somewhere and when I generate the war , the constraints should get copied from that file into web.xml, Kind of like a build script which appends the above code to web.xml so that once war is generated its ready to be deployed.